# How to limit Input field character throught angular project

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, forms, validation

I have to add limit on all input fields in my angular application when user exceed limit I have
to notify user that he exceed max limit. I can Implement this individual on every input but I want generic method like by using service etc to add limit on multliple Inputs .

Answer (score 0):

Validators need to be registered against every instance of the form field, so it's not possible to avoid placing the Validator directive (as a HTML attribute for template-driven form fields or in the `validators` array for reactive form fields) on every `<input>`

That said, depending on your use case you could achieve what you are after by creating a custom form field component which wraps your input, e.g.

**Template driven**

`custom-input.component.html`

```
<input maxlength="100" [(ngModel)]="inputValue" />
```

`custom-input.component.ts`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'custom-input'
})
export class CustomInput {
  inputValue: string;
}
```

**Reactive**

`custom-input.component.html`

```
<input [formControl]="inputFormControl" />
```

`custom-input.component.ts`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'custom-input'
})
export class CustomInput {
  inputFormControl: FormControl = new FormControl('', Validators.maxLength(100));
}
```

*Note: This is a very simple example to demonstrate the point, the internals of the components will need to be handled differently if you have more complex use cases, like multiple validators and dynamic addition/removal of validators*

This component can then be used anywhere you would have used  and you won't need to keep retyping `maxlength="100"` or `new FormControl('', Validators.maxLength(100))`every time.

For a more scalable solution it is also worth looking into implementing your own custom form controls via implementing the `ControlValueAccessor` interface. See [this guide](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-custom-form-controls/)